# as3 creating and deleting children

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to make it when a button is hit it creates a child and then when the child is hit it deletes the child....this works but then when I click the button again the child doesn't get created again.

How can I do this? Here is my code:

```
var bikeride:MovieClip = new ridingbike();
ridinb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openbike); 
function openbike(evt:MouseEvent):void { 

addChild(bikeride);
} 


bikeride.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closebike); 
function closebike(evt:MouseEvent):void { 
    bikeride.removeChildAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the child using:

```
removeChild(bikeride);;
```

If you don't store the `bikeride` instance you can do this:

```
function closebike(evt:MouseEvent):void { 
    var bike:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(evt.target);
    bike.parent.removeChild(bike);
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks. What is wrong with the method I am using if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: **@Butterflycode** You are trying to remove the first child who was added to `bikeride`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Florent's answer you may want to also remove the event listeners and check if `bikeride` has a parent before trying to work with it. This avoids null object reference errors and to ensure that `bikeride` gets garbage collected (removed from memory, freeing resources).

```
bikeride.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closebike); 

function closebike(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(bikeride.parent)
    {
        bikeride.parent.removeChild(bikeride);
    }

    bikeride.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closebike);
}
```

It is really important to remove event listeners if you're expecting your object to get properly 'deleted'.